# handeling java RMI connection refused to host exception

Tags: java, rmi

I want to show a an error message to user if the server is not started.
when user is starting the program.
below I mention my ServerConnector singleton class which I used to connect to server allover the application.

```
public class ServerConnector {



private static ServerConnector serverConnector;
    private RemoteFactory remoteFactory;

    private ServerConnector() throws NotBoundException, MalformedURLException,
            RemoteException {
        remoteFactory = (RemoteFactory) Naming
                .lookup("rmi://localhost:5050/RoomReservation");
    }

    public static ServerConnector getServerConnector()
            throws NotBoundException, MalformedURLException, RemoteException {
        if (serverConnector == null) {
            serverConnector = new ServerConnector();
        }
        return serverConnector;
    }

    public CustomerController getCustomerController() throws RemoteException {
        return remoteFactory.getCustomerController();
    }


}
```

is there any way to check the server is started before loading a GUI of the program?

Thank you.

Comment: Use a try catch block to set a flag. And use this to update your GUI to display the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Catch `java.rmi.ConnectException`. That means the *Registry* hasn't been started.
- Catch `NotBoundException`. That means the server hasn't been bound to the Registry.